# Clearing the buffer for multiple inputs in the same line

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

Is there an away to clear the buffer after each input while having multiple inputs in one line?
I've been capturing each variable one at a time and clearing the buffer as such:

```
cin >> length;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
```

is the same some how possible with this line of code:

```
cin >> length >> width >> height;
```

Comment: Why do you want to clear the buffer in this case? `cin >> length >> width >> height;` will work prefectly well without clearing the buffer.

Comment: To answer the question though, you could do this by writing a custom manipulator

Comment: @john after considering the problem I realize I don't. I had just been trying to simplify and condense the code and created a problem in my head that didn't exist. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom manipulator

```
istream& clear_buffer(istream& in)
{
    in.clear();
    in.ignore(10000, '\n');
    return in;
}

cin >> length >> clear_buffer >> width >> clear_buffer >> height >> clear_buffer;
```